# How to run ng serve in development mode without minifying JS files

Tags: angular, angular-cli

running Angular 5 with ng serve would generate minified js files.  is there a way to not do that so its easier to debug?

or is there another way to debug Angular 5 app with ng serve?

Comment: Whats hard for you to debug? If you place a `debugger` statement in `app.component.ts` you should see the unminified source with dev-tools.  Make sure your source maps are enabled in Dev tool settings.

Comment: @cgatian thank you, my friend.  that worked :)

Comment: In chrome if you press Ctrl+p while viewing source you can open the file by typing it's name.

Answer (score 0):

### The possible solution is:-

### To use debug in your app

```
1) Assuming, you are using Visual Studio Code, you can 'install debugger 
    for chrome extensions'.
2) Open configurations in debug window and launch.json will open(edit your 
   launch.json if you require).
3) Start debug.
```